# Suscpectibility in Ising networks

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, phase-transition, ising-model, fluctuation-dissipation

I am struggling to find good references on how the susceptibility described phase transitions in Ising networks. First of all i struggle to find a good defintion for the susceptibility.
I understood it as
$$
\chi = \frac{\partial M}{\partial H},
$$
where $M$ is the magnetization given by
$$
M=\sum_i \sigma_i
$$
and $H=- \frac{1}{2}A_{ij}\sigma_i \sigma_j$ is the Hamiltonian, with $A_{ij}$ the adjacency matrix of the network where we implement our Ising network on.

Using the fluctuation-dissipation theorem we can rewrite this as
$$
\chi = \beta ( \langle M^2 \rangle - \langle M \rangle^2).
$$
I have four major questions:

1. How does the susceptibility characterise a phase transition? Why does it peak at a phase transition. How would one define this type of phase transition in general?
2. What does the fluctuation-dissipation theorem state, what does it mean in terms of Ising networks and how can we use to to rewrite $\chi$ as $\beta ( \langle M^2 \rangle - \langle M \rangle^2)$?
3. How should we interpret $\langle \rangle$? And how can we compute/approximate $\beta ( \langle M^2 \rangle - \langle M \rangle^2)$ given actual spin configurations provided by e.g. simulations of an Ising network evolved by Metropolis-Hasting algorithms?
4. How are Ising models used to make more universal statements about phase transitions in other types of systems? I heard it has something to do with universality classes, but I don't understand anything regarding this topic.

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated. Even if someone could provide me proper references in order to further explore these questions, that would be extremely helpful!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Susceptibility is usually defined as the derivative of $M$ with respect to the external magnetic field, not the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1):

The fluctuation dissipation theorem tell you that the response of your system to perturbations is determined by its fluctuations without perturbations. In your case, you could run a simulation at zero external field and calculate the fluctuations of the magnetization  . Then you can repeat the simulations for many values of the external field and calculate the slope of the mean magnetization against the field. You should find that the two results are the same.

Ising model has a list of scaling relations that are found in many systems, I guess that is why it is called a universality class. For example the square root dependence of magnetization on temperature near the transition point, or the cubic root time dependence of the size of magnetic domains during relaxation. The experimental data of liquid gas transition of many small molecules collapse on some some of these scaling relations when they are rescaled by their critical temperatures.

Comment: The square root dependence only holds in the mean field theory though.